# How to Change Configuration of Device with Fixed IP Address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have Antminer S4 unit (Bitcoin miner) with an Ethernet interface that has been pre-configured to an IP address of 198.162.1.110 (big assumption).  I hook it up to my Internet service providers modem/wireless router.  I need to open the 198.162.1.110 and change its setup (instructions here https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=813417).  My Windows 8 laptop only have wireless card so I can only connect to the ISP wireless router wireless.  When I open 198.162.1.110, I cannot reach from my laptop.  I googled around and found my ISP's router 198.162.0.1.  I have another old off the shell wireless router with me that I can plug Antminer S4 directly and connect my laptop.   Why is ISP router (DHCP) not working with this fixed IP Antminer S4?  Also, is there a way to find out what is the real IP of Antminer?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your S4 isn't being assigned 192.162.1.110 if your subnet is 192.162.0.1.  Log into your router's configuration website, go the page with page which lists the devices connected to it, and determine which ip address is actually being assigned

Comment: @Ramhound S4 on bootup displays IP of 198.162.1.110.  I assume that is local IP that is assigned by the router.  Is there a way to get the IP pinging the network?

Comment: Your going to have to change your routers subnet then.

Comment: @Ramhound what would my routers subnet would be if IP of S4 is 198.162.1.110?

Comment: Ipconfig, in a command prompt, you tell us?

Comment: Ramhound: Could be.  (In the admittedly unlikely case of a /23.)

Comment: **Careful!** The rfc1918 space commonly used for local nets is **192.168.0.0/16** or less formally 192.168.x.x. 198.162.1.0/24 and 192.162.0.0/22 are public addresses assigned to entities in Canada and Russia, shouldn't be used in this situation, and I'd bet aren't. OP: check your router's config and make sure the subnet mask on its LAN side includes the desired address -- as TOOGAM suggests this is /23 or _less_ in modern (CIDR) notation -- then restart the Antminer while running Wireshark on the PC and look especially at any (G)ARP or DHCP traffic. And/or try nmap.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your comments.  I found the solution. @RamHound was right.  I could have changed the subnet of router to my match fixed IP 192.162.1.110, where I assign router 192.162.1.1 instead of 192.162.0.1 (default).   I had a spare wireless router around.  I connect wireless router to the S4 box with a ethernet cable.  This created a LAN network without no internet connection. Then connect to IP shown on the S4 display via a wireless card of my laptop.  Went to setting and change it to DHCP.  The guy who sold me shipped it with FIXED IP.  Now I am in DHCP mode.  Plug and play!